# Azure DevOps: Assets file doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2/linux-x64'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, nuget-package-restore

I'm creating a build pipeline for a AspNet Core Web Api in Azure DevOps using a task group that first installs .Net Core SDK (2.2), then does a package restore using `dotnet restore` (that uses a VSTS feed) and then builds the project.

At the build step, I supply the following arguments:

`--configuration Release --runtime $(Target Platform) --no-restore /p:Version=$(Major Version).$(Minor Version).$(Build.BuildNumber)`.

All the steps up to `build` step are successful. However, I get the following error at the build step:

```
[command]C:\windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
[command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe build D:\a\1\s\WebApp\WebApp.csproj --configuration Release --runtime linux-x64 --no-restore /p:Version=1.0.40
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.2.32702+c4012a063 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\2.2.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(208,5): error NETSDK1047: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\WebApp\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2/linux-x64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp2.2' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'linux-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers. [D:\a\1\s\WebApp\WebApp.csproj]

Build FAILED.

C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\2.2.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(208,5): error NETSDK1047: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\WebApp\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2/linux-x64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp2.2' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'linux-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers. [D:\a\1\s\WebApp\WebApp.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.53
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : D:\a\1\s\WebApp\WebApp.csproj
##[section]Finishing: Build
```

I checked out older answers related Visual Studio however, could not find something related to Azure DevOps pipelines.

Comment: Locally I guess there is no issue?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Yeah, locally no issue.

Comment: Try to run `dotnet --info` locally and in the pipeline before the build and check if there are differences.

Comment: There are differences like the patch version of the .Net Core SDK. What kind of difference I should be looking for?

Comment: If it's only the patch I think it should work. do you upload the obj/bin folders to the source control?

Comment: No, I didn't upload any build output.

Answer (score 6):

To solve this issue, please try with deleting `--no-restore`.

To explain why it's no issue locally, that's because while you build the project locally, it is using the previous version of **obj** file which exists in the cache if the current file does not satisfied the compile condition. You can try with deleting the **bin** and **obj** files locally, and run these commands again. You will also see the same error. It was the error I ever meet locally, and solved with deleting `--no-restore`.

As default, if you did not specified the `--runtime linux-x64`, the RID of package it restored is `win-x64`. You can test with only run **dotnet restore** task in Azure Devops by using self-hosted agent, and check the project.assets.json file:

[image]

You will see that without specifying, the defaulted RID of the package it restored is `win-x64`. Same to the **dotnet build** task, since **starting with .NET Core 2.0 SDK, dotnet restore runs implicitly when you run dotnet build**:

[image]

At this time, if you specified `--no-restore` in `dotnet build`, as default, it will use the package which restored by the task "dotnet restore" which RID is `win-x64`. **But** in your build task, you specified the `runtime` of build as `linux-x64`. This does not match the package. That's why you receive the message: `error NETSDK1047: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\WebApp\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2/linux-x64'.`

Just delete `--no-restore` and try again

[image]

the error message should disappeared.

Comment: I agree with the reason why I'm getting the error. But not sure if I can delete `dotnet restore` because I do not have a Nuget.config in my project and hence, pipelines won't know that it needs to use a private nuget feed. I think I should use `dotnet restore -r linux-x64 -s "path/to/nuget/config"` in the step before the build step?

Comment: Don't need delete `dotnet restore`, just delete the `--no-restore` in dotnet build is okay.

Comment: If I delete it, it will try to do an implicit restore right? But it doesn't have a Nuget.config to perform this restore. So, which Nuget sources will it use for this implicit restore?

Comment: Yes, it will. But also, you don't need worry about without Nuget,config file in your repos. See this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior. If the server could not found Nuget.config in the root path of your project file, it will use the global Nuget.config which exists in your build machine. As default, the global Nuget.config locate in `%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` if the machine is Windows.

Comment: So, even if you specified `--no-restore`. It will also can restore relevant packages.

Comment: @swedon Hi, how the things going. Does removing --no-restore could solve the error? Feel free to let me know how the result is.

Comment: No, I had to add a step before Package Restore called Nuget Authenticate and then add a Nuget.Config file to the project.

Comment: Do you mind share your solution here and accept it then, thus other SO users can refer to this solution?

Comment: For what it's worth, removing `--no-restore` did work for me when I had that same error (but with '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0/win-x64'). I can't accept your answer, but I can give you a +1. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `--no-restore` isn't always going to work. You may be using a dedicated `dotnet restore` task in your pipeline so your restore comes from a private ADO Artifacts feed. The implicit restore may not reference your private feed. You can edit your `.csproj` file and add the runtime IDs as the error suggests, in the same property group like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-x64;win-x86;win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This will let you leave the `--no-restore` in place.